# Is retitling sufficient for a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, new-users

If we find questions with titles that do not match the preferred form (*"Pygame: I have a problem!"*, for example), does a new title including some basic relevant information about the question (*"Why won't my sprites collide correctly?"* as an alternative to the example), potentially adding tags, constitute a 'substantial' edit?

I understand that retag-only suggested-edits are liable to be rejected, but I feel that the question's title is considerably more important. I am prepared to be wrong about this.

Comment: Why are they mutually exclusive? Both correct tagging and a good title is important. What's going to get rejected is an edit that just adds some (minor) tags while leaving blatant problems like that horrible title in the question.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I'm wont the believe that tags are only slightly less important than title (which is, that they're really quite important), but I've seen mixed results from retag and retitle suggestions (for better or worse). So I'm bothering people about it directly~ I feel like the more rep a user has, the more important that `+2` seems to be to them...

Comment: I guess there's no reason not to link the question that made me ask. I put in the edit suggestion, but, as predicted, there's managed to be some disagreement.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740546/pygame-a-simple-game-example

Comment: Retag-only suggested edits should *not* be getting rejected. Some people still cling to the idea that only edits which address a substantial number of problems in a post should be approved, even though we purposefully got rid of the "too minor" rejection reason a while ago. I say, if your edit improves the post, go for it. If you have the time or inclination to address more than the issue you first noticed, that's great, but if not, that's no reason to let a good edit go to waste.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I remember reading about the removal of the too-minor reason, but it looks a lot like people have just started using this not-significant canned rationale instead...

Answer (score 3):

As one of the reviewers who accepted the edit you linked in the comments, I'll explain what factors lead me to accepting that particular edit.

- The original title was *really* terrible, the title you suggested descried the question a lot better. Because of the huge improvement, and the overall quality of the rest of the question, this alone would probably already have me accepting the edit.
- You added some tags that described the problem, next to the tags that the op submitted that just described the technologies used. Not the most necessary edit, but perfectly fine to make while you're doing the title anyway. (Not the most necessary since I suspect not a lot of people will find the question through these new tags: refresh has 6 followers, lag has 3). I might have rejected an edit only adding these tags for being superfluous.
- You made some small edits in the question text, which indicates that you have actually read it thoroughly. With some suggested edits, this seems to be missing completely. Again, if you had only made the edit in the text, while leaving that horrible title, I might have rejected.

Seeing that you did all these things, and the rest of the question was perfectly readable, I feel you did your best to improve the question and succeeded in doing so. I have no idea why anyone would reject that particular edit.

In general, I think that the reason reviewers don't like minor edits is the fact that every one of those edits requires three reviewers to look at it, and this has to be done for every little edit that is suggested. This can be found especially irritating when the edit leaves a lot of further work to be done to the question to get it in good shape, which might have to be reviewed again. Doing one edit that fixes most of the problems is much more time-effective. I'd recommend to, at least as long as your edits have to be reviewed, make your edits substantial. And with that I mean, check the title, the text and the tags for anything that really needs to be fixed. I feel the best way to get you edit rejected is doing a minor edit while there are more, possibly even bigger, problems with the question.

Comment: I generally do as much as I can, but I tend away from edits that might be construed as altering the message of the post. I can sympathize with reviewers feeling that they're being dragged out for a pittance, but I also have no appetite for fussing over edits and then having them rejected because they're too far-reaching (and there have been many times where it would be easy to start taking liberties). I had not considered that questions would be recycled through the review queue, though, when new edits come through. That's gotta be pretty annoying. :s

Comment: Sure, you should take care in not changing the original author's intent, which can make editing really difficult. However, keep in mind that there's no use in 'polishing a turd': if a question is so difficult to interpret you just don't know what to do, don't suggest any edit, but flag as 'Unclear what you're asking'.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bit of a gray area and everyone will have different thresholds but from a general point of view edits of titles can be as valuable as any other edit.

Please don't forget that if you suggest an edit it should be a complete edit, i.e. improving the post in all places where it can be improved.

Often if only half the work is done, I reject it and do a complete edit myself.

Why the rejection of insubstantial edits? Well, to avoid meaningless, not improving modifications. This would be just noise. The improvement must be significant, otherwise edits would be just edits for the sake of editing.

But in cases where everything except the title or same small words in the text or some tags is okay, I still accept them, because my threshold for substantiality is rather low. If it improves the post, even a small improvement is worth to have on SO!

To give some examples:

Title was "I have a problem", suggested "Need to find the contour of a glass in an image", post otherwise fine -> Accept, because changing the title here is a substantial improvement

Title was "PyGame: How to synchronize the framerate", suggested "How to synchronize the framerate", post otherwise okay -> Reject, not substantial (maybe in conjunction with other edits)

Question about method resolution order in Python and Python tag is missing, suggested to add python tag and post is otherwise okay -> Accept, because python tag is essential to this question

Comment: `Often if only half the work is done, I reject it and do a complete edit myself.` Wouldn't it be a bit classier to *accept* the edit and then revise the rest yourself, instead of rejecting a legitimate suggestion, copying its content, adding a little, and then approving it as your own work? I was under the impression that a reviewer's job was only to filter out destructive edits, not to review the entire post and add their own content to edit suggestions. I feel like the extra criterion of having to *perfect the post entirely* is actually completely unreasonable, but I may be misreading you.

Comment: @Augusta Yes that's also a possibility. It depends, maybe I reject it if it only does 20% of the necessary work. Maybe 50% is already okay. But requiring an edit to be complete is very reasonable. It avoids consecutive minor edits. If you already try an edit you can as well repair everything that is wrong. This was also pointed out somewhere else here on meta but I do not remember where unfortunately.

Comment: I would assume, then, that for an edit to satisfy you, it would *not* need to include revisions to inescapably ambiguous or vague content, where the author's meaning cannot be strictly determined, yes? I've seen no small number of posts where the author says something that can be interpreted in multiple ways, or no specific way, and cannot be clarified without the author's direct intervention. These are clear shortfalls in the post, but cannot be fixed by third parties. Would you say that an edit that resolves *as much -knowable- content as possible* to be satisfactory, even if it's only ~25%?

Comment: @Augusta This is a somewhat unrelated but interesting aspect of editing. Surely you always have to interpret the original author when modifying their contribution. The ideal case is asking and clarifying. But if this is not possible we arrive at another gray area. I guess this could be another question here.

Comment: Ha ha, there certainly are some uniquely baffling posts here. A recent one I've seen asks how to determine collisions between "`draw.rect and draw.circle`". Do they mean the geometry of the figures these functions produce? The Rects that the functions return? A mask produced based on those bitmaps? Or maybe a fourth thing I can't even imagine? Because the exact interpretation is open to debate, I would assume that it is invalid for editing and that anything which alters it, save clarification from/by the author, is necessarily rejectable since it potentially changes the point of the post.

Comment: @Augusta Come on. Just don't try to alter the meaning of the post too much. (whatever this means) We all have some inbuilt statistical module and we make an implicit statistical test and then we apply what is typically called common sense and we kind of watch each other. The outcome is remarkably good. If you want to discuss this, please open another question. Will surely be interesting.

Comment: Oh, I get that part. Rather, what I'm curious about is how your assessment of a valid but non-perfecting edit suggestion accounts for dubious situations, rather than when it's appropriate to second- (or even first-) guess an author. Obviously, we have to judge what someone means when they're unclear, because that's what editing is. But I can't imagine a way to get shut down more quick than introducing meaning where it clearly doesn't exist (not that you're suggesting that). In short, does that non-perfecting post that "does all it can" represent a 20% job, or a 100% job? :y

Comment: * Sorry, that was a little unclear-- it "corrects all incontrovertible flaws," but leaves debatable or vague ones untouched. (Where the post remains 80% necessarily unclear.)

Comment: @Augusta I would say it is a 100% job then. If you cannot really correct it with good consience, just leave these parts as they are and put a comment below the question. I would accept an edit that only corrects the things that can be correct without doubt. :)

Comment: That's what I had imagined, but I was curious about it since there's no way to differentiate, at a glance, between restraint on an unclear passage and simply overlooking it. (I don't expect reviewers to examine comments and context, even though this would probably solve a lot of problems. -_-) Anyway, thanks for discussing it! It's great to hear more about how people go about these things!